# PHP Form: One to many UI relationships, represented in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, one-to-many

I have a simple problem, but for some reason cannot figure out the words to find a solution (or which I'm sure there are many).  I'm building a simple PHP form for a user, who may have zero-to-infinite phone numbers and one-to-infinite email-addresses.

I want one PHP page which allows me to click a button like "add new phone number" and another phone number field pops up.  Next to each field should be a delete icon which removes that row.  When I submit the form I want to be able to process it in PHP, ideally in a simple way.

The problem is I'm manually writing out the jQuery line-by-line and trying to build a framework to make it so I can easily apply this to other fields.  Then I realized it must have been done already, and I'm reinventing the wheel.

Does anyone know of any simple one-to-many tools to spare me reinventing the wheel?

**UPDATE** Turns out I should have been searching for "form element repeater" or "form input cloning" or some similar phrase, instead of "jquery one to many inputs".  The new phrases yielded the results found in my accepted (my own) answer.

Comment: Do you already have the code to do it once?

Comment: I wrote code for one specific field, but even it is incomplete.  At present when you click the delete icons remove that row the IDs for the rows aren't consecutive.  So if you had one phone number (ID/name of "phone1") and add two more ("phone2" and "phone3"), then delete the middle one, you are left with "phone1" and "phone3".  I can keep chugging along and correct this issue, but again, I feel like I must be reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Databases don't care if the IDs are consecutive or not.  Actually, very frequently they're not.  People who use databases also dont like the idea of "deleting" information, so often times they just add a new column called "active" so when a user "deletes" the info is still in the database, just not referenced by the queries.  I know im not exactly answering the question, but maybe we can simplify it?

Comment: It's not the database ID I meant, but the HTML ID.  Really the HTML input's "name" attribute is more important, since that's what the PHP processing page references.  In PHP I'd write a loop looking for "phone1" then "phone2" and breaking when the next name couldn't be found.  Unless I'm doing it wrong and should be passing it as an array.  Hence my question looking for best practices/existing solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two frameworks:

SheepIt: http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB&sec=home

jQuery Form Element Repeater Plugin: https://github.com/cballou/jQuery-Form-Element-Repeater-Plugin

Comment: You dont need a plugin for something so simple let alone two plugins. Two extra http requests for something that might take 10 lines

Comment: I was just providing two options which solved my need.  I personally went with the SheepIt route, but wasn't able to choose my own answer for two days, so it's unchecked as of yet.  I'm not sure where you're getting the two HTTP requests from (they both offer small downloadable scripts to self-host), nor do I see how you can replicate their functionality in 10 lines, but I'd love to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-input').click(function(){
   var  num =  $(this).attr('data-num'),
          $newInput = $('<input data-input="' + num + '" type="tel"/>'),
          $delete = $('<a class='delete'/>');

    $delete.on('click', function(ev){
         $newInput.remove();
     });

     $('#formName').append($newInput + $delete);
 }) ;
```

Something along the lines of this should work fine. It generates a input and delete button attaching a click event to the delete button generated and uses data attributes so you can keep track of inputs through PHP.

Comment: Sorry if the indenting is weird put this together on my phone

Comment: I tried turning your example into a jsFiddle (which I should probably do for my own code) and didn't follow your code very well.  Here's what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/9L6CB/

Answer (score 0):

As a simple alternative maybe you could have one input box and separate the multiple entries with semi-colons or some other marker. Then in the php script you could use the `explode` function to separate them out into an array. e.g. :

`johndoe@gahoo.com; janedoe@gahoo.com;jamesdoe@gahoo.com;`

This would allow cut and paste of e.g. strings of email addresses, so for some applications it might be a preferable solution, as well as requiring minimal coding

Answer (score 0):

Your html code should look like this `<input name="phonenumber[]">`

Your jquery code will look like this

```
$('#add_phonenumber').click(function(){
 $('#my_form').append('<input name="phonenumber[]">'); //add 
});
$('.delete_me').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('span or div').find('input').remove(); // delete (NOTE: your delete button and an input must be in one container for each input)
});

<span class="inputs"><input type="text" name="phonenumber[]"><a class="delete_me">delete this input</a></span>
```

Your php form handler

```
$new = array();

$phones = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$count = count( $phones );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( $phones[$i] != '' ) :
        $new[$i]['phonenumber'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $phones[$i] ) );
    endif;
}

// now array $new contains your phone numbers, you can save it or whatever you want to do with it
```